# How to setting Google Sign-In for Google+ not show by popup

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth, signing

I implement G+ sign-in function in my site, document [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/). The problem is google show sign-in dialog by popup. This way make my site break in iOS if I bookmark it home screen. It cannot close the popup. Does it has some options to open sign-in by another way?

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue with facebook login. Can anyone help me to prevent these popup?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, but it's slightly more complicated.

You can follow the instructions in the Google [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) documentation.  Broadly, it involves directing the user to an authorization endpoint from which you get back a code. You then exchange that code at the token endpoint for access, ID, and refresh tokens.

The best way to learn how this flow works in an interactive way is using the [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).  Try entering `profile email openid` in the "input your own scopes" box, then tap Authorize APIs.  Here's an [example auth URL](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email%20profile%20openid&prompt=select_account&access_type=offline).

The docs for [verifying the ID Token](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token) detail how to use the ID Token to authenticate the user, by extracting the `sub` value.